# Forms accessibility - actions on buttons

Tags: forms, accessibility

I have a Shopping Cart and for example there is a `<button>` that will trigger an action to add an item to the cart.

And my dilemma is: 
- should I just have a standalone button with JS hook that sends a POST request to an API to add/update an item to cart?
- or should I wrap it in a `<form>` with hidden `<input>`s and then when there is no JS the button will be working because form will be submitted and when JS enabled I will submit the form via JS.

But when not using `<form>` with `<input>`s but just simple `<button>` the code would be cleaner.
And nowadays many pages need JS to be running.
Who switches JS off?

So should I bother to provide no-JS functionality at all?

Maybe I should bother only for public sector websites to provide it?

In my case JS would not be an enhancement but replacement for the default form functionality as you see.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's perfectly acceptable to require javascript these days. It may even provide a better and more accessible user experience in some cases.

That being said, it's also very important to provide graceful fall-backs for clients that don't have javascript enabled for whatever reason. In the very minimum, there should be some sort of a warning or alert letting the user know that basic functionality won't work without Javascript.

Comment: Hi @Josh. Thank you for your opinion. I see websites that their main content is even generated by JS, Google of course indexes it, but then without JS such a page is not accessible at all. In my case with the cart only this functionality is not accessible without JS. Of course I can make it work both ways and make it as well accessible but is it worth it additional time - the percentage of people without JS would be probably very low, I bet that below 1%.

Comment: I agree with you that the percentage of your audience without Javascript enabled will probably be pretty low. However, even 1% can turn into significant numbers, if you operate a high-volume website with thousands of daily visitors. If it's a smaller website, with relatively low traffic, I'd probably just create a warning or alert.

Comment: OK. You are right. But for example on Youtube without JS you will see nothing :) On Facebook on there other hand there is a message.

Comment: YouTube does a horrible job of this. For what it's worth, Google Maps gives a warning, asking the user to enable Javascript, and Google Search has a fallback to provide full functionality without JavaScript. The YouTube example may have something to do with the fact that YouTube requires either Javascript or Flash to prevent downloading of videos. They should still have a warning though.